# «Например» в начале предложения — пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

1. Нужно есть фрукты и овощи, потому что они дают витамины. Например груша, яблоко, морковь.
2. Заниматься спортом тоже важно. Например играть в теннис, в волейбол или делать гимнастику.

Какой знак препинания нужен после слова «например» (если нужен вообще)?

Answer (score 2):

1. «Нужно есть фрукты и овощи, потому что они дают витамины. Например груша, яблоко, морковь».

Первое. При таком порядке слов возникает ощущение, что Вы перечисляете не овощи и фрукты, а витамины (так как слово "например" стоит ближе к витаминам).
[Сравните (с малоизвестными названиями): Нужно есть фрукты и овощи, потому что они дают витамины. Например, личи, фейхоа, тамаринд.]

Второе. Если не переделывать предложения, то нужно после "например" поставить запятую. И, думаю, лучше использовать множественное число существительных:
*Нужно есть фрукты и овощи, потому что они дают витамины. Например, груши, яблоки, морковь.*

Я бы все-таки убрала двусмысленность и написала так:
**Нужно есть фрукты и овощи (например, груши, яблоки, морковь), потому что они дают витамины.**

2. *Заниматься спортом тоже важно. Например, играть в теннис, в волейбол или делать гимнастику.*

Пояснение:
если «например» относится к целому предложению, то оно отделяется запятой;
если оборот с «например» выделен скобками или тире, то после «например» ставится запятая.

[Знаки препинания в предложениях со словом «например»](https://pishugramotno.ru/punktuacia/slovo-naprimer-vydelyaetsya-zapyatymi)